# SQL Server host not found error with sequelize

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I am trying to use SQL Server with node.js using sequelize orm. But I keep getting host not found error:

> HostNotFoundError [SequelizeHostNotFoundError]: Failed to connect to
>   localhost//SQLEXPRESS:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost//SQLEXPRESS
>
> Failed to connect to localhost//SQLEXPRESS:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost//SQLEXPRESS', code: 'ESOCKET

Code:

```
var db = new Sequelize('test', 'root', 'secret', {
    host: 'localhost\\SQLEXPRESS',
    dialect: 'mssql',

    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      idle: 10000
    },
  });

  db.authenticate()
  .then(()=>console.log('Database connected'))
  .catch(err=> console.log(err))
```

Please help me!

Comment: And **have you installed** SQL Server **Express** on your local machine??

Comment: Yes I have sql server express installed locally on runs on port 56198

Answer (score 4, accepted):

trying
options.port   The port of the relational database.

```
var db = new Sequelize('test', 'root', 'secret', {
  host: 'localhost\\SQLEXPRESS',
  dialect: 'mssql',

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },
  port:56198,
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked but I finally ended up using the Azure SQL DB directly in my program even for local tests. Just added my ip to the firewall exclusion and worked like a charm. I think it doesn't make much of a cost difference running the SQL Express locally and using the azure DB directly...